# Comparison between different datatypes, specifically string and list

Tags: python

`'a' >= ['a']` gives an error saying they are different data sets but `'a' == ['a']` gives False. Why?

I expected the latter would also give an error. My research shows that it is because of the way rules are made in Python. If that's the case what is the reason to allow the latter but not the former?

Comment: because == means if the string it  is the same of the other value ... but in the first one you are saying if the string "a" is greater than the list or equal ... do you think the string greater or you see that you can't compare them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a quirk of Python's comparison rules. In Python, comparing objects of different types using `==` and `!=` is allowed and will generally result in a `False` or `True` respectively, even if the comparison might not make immediate "real-world" sense (like comparing a `string` to a `list`). This makes it possible to use these comparison operators in a broad variety of contexts without necessarily raising an error.

On the other hand, **ordering comparisons** (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) between different data types raise a `TypeError` in Python 3. This is to avoid the potential ambiguity and confusion that could arise from attempting to order disparate types. Python 2 did allow such comparisons, but it was often a source of subtle bugs and misunderstandings, so this behavior was changed in Python 3.

To understand the underlying logic behind this design choice, consider this: equality (or its negation) is a more universally applicable concept than ordering. Almost any two objects, regardless of type, can be meaningfully compared for equality. They either are the same or they aren't. But what does it mean to say one object is "less than" another if they're of completely different types? The semantics become unclear.

Let's break down the two comparisons you mentioned:

1. `'a' >= ['a']`: This attempts to determine if the string `'a'` is greater than or equal to the list `['a']`. Since these are different data types and the context is an ordering comparison, Python 3 raises a `TypeError`.
2. `'a' == ['a']`: This checks if the string `'a'` is equal to the list `['a']`. They are clearly not the same thing, so the result is `False`. Python doesn't raise an error here because it's simply checking for equality.

This design decision in Python 3 helps to prevent subtle and unexpected bugs by making it clear that ordering comparisons between different data types are not allowed, while still allowing the more universal equality comparisons.

Comment: But the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) never says so. According to the doc, `'a' == ['a']` first calls `'a'.__eq__(['a'])`, which returns `NotImplemented`, then calls `['a'].__eq__('a')`, which also returns `NotImplemented`, and finally defaults to `object.__eq__('a', ['a'])`, which still returns `NotImplemented` because it only returns `True` when the two are of equal identity, or `NotImplemented` otherwise. There is simply no documented explanation for why `False` is returned when comparing two objects of different types for equality.

Comment: @blhsing That's the documentation for *implementing* operators, which only documents the *minimal* behaviour required by the implementation. The meaning of operators is documented in [expressions: Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons), which documents the *expected* behaviour.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's what I already said about the default behavior of falling back to `object.__eq__` for identity-based comparison. So tell me, how exactly can `True if x is y else NotImplemented` ever be evaluated to `False`?

Comment: @blhsing `NotImplemented` from both operands means the default behaviour applies, and "The default behavior for equality comparison (== and !=) is based on the identity of the objects."

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Did you even read my first comment? That's what I already said, that `NotImplemented` from calling the `__eq__` method of both operands means falling back to the default `object.__eq__` method, which returns `True if x is y else NotImplemented`, which is `NotImplemented` in this case since `'a' is ['a']` is not true. No way for `False` to be returned according to the documentation.

Comment: @blhsing The `==`/`operator.__eq__` isn’t the `__eq__` *method*, it uses them. When both operands' `__eq__` methods default to `NotImplemented`, there is still a *third* case that gets evaluated by `==` namely the fallback identity check. The default `object.__eq__` is merely the default for the *method* but not the *operator*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Once again you either did not read my first comment or did not try to comprehend it. I said, "...and finally *defaults* to `object.__eq__('a', ['a'])`, which still returns `NotImplemented` *because it only returns True when the two are of equal identity*," THAT is the third case, the identity check, you're so eager to point me to. The documentation I linked to details the exact logics of how the operator `==` works--by trying to call the `__eq__` method of the two operands, and defaulting to the `__eq__` method of `object`. None of them returns `False` for the OP's case. The end.

Comment: @blhsing I am well aware of what you wrote and I still see you conflating the methods and the operator. As the docs say, *types* inherit the default behaviour of `object`, i.e. the comparison *methods*. The *operators* are more than the methods (consider how `len` does a size check even when `__len__` does not). That is where "The default behavior for equality comparison (== and !=) is based on the identity of the objects." lives. Having `object.__eq__` *also* check for identity is a separate mechanism that provides a fast path but isn’t needed.

Comment: @blhsing Notice how the linked docs on operators also talks about the default for ordering. In this case too it is the ordering operator that raises `TypeError`, not any operands' ordering method.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Of course it is obvious from the actual output that the `==` operator is doing more than just calling the `__eq__` methods of the operands and their types in the MROs. All I'm trying to say is that the behavior that the OP observes is not a documented one.

Comment: @blhsing It is documented: "*The default behavior for equality comparison* (== and !=) is based on the identity of the objects. Hence, equality comparison of instances with the same identity results in equality, and equality comparison of instances with different identities results in inequality." From above linked docs. Likewise, there’s a part on ordering. Both of these are in line with what OP observed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Let's just say that `object.__eq__` is either wholly redundant because there's always a hidden identity-based comparison to fall back on even when `object.__eq__` returns `NotImplemented`, or implemented incorrectly because it should just return `x is y` so that there is no need for a hidden identity-based comparison since all Python objects are of type `object` and will naturally fall back to `object.__eq__` for a final, identity-based comparison.